# Hub site page global navigation inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modern-pages, global-navigation, hub-site, top-navigation

I've spent hours reading about global navigation but I can't seem to find a definite answer. I understand that pages created under a hub site will inherit the global navigation menu from the hub site. Are we able to disable inheritance for pages created under the hub site to create custom navigation menu for individual pages. Thank you.

Example:

**Homepage**

- Workshop - Global navigation menu

**Sub-Page**

- Car - Car Navigation menu (Custom navigation)
- Motorbike - Motorbike navigation menu (Custom navigation)

Answer (score 0):

I regret to inform that you are unable to add separated global navigation bars into different pages at this time.

You could only modify the navigation bar in the site collections or sub sites.